# jquery/css wrap text bottom up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

I am trying to wrap text in a div using css and/or jQuery such that the bottom line is the longest.

so rather than

```
__________
|this is |
|text    |
|________|
```

it would say

```
__________
|this    |
|is text |
|________|
```

I can easily wrap the text using

```
    white-space: pre-wrap;
```

But i can't find anything that would let me do this.

(one thought i had would be to reverse the text, find where the line wrapping happens, apply a `<br/>` in the same places, with the text going forward.. but i dont know how to check where the line wraps)

Comment: A more modern duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423951/wrap-text-from-bottom-to-top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the route, of reversing, checking where the line breaks were, and then inserting them accordingly. Please feel free to use my function. This function accepts a jQuery element (with text that already wraps), and re-wraps it's text upward.

```
function wrapUp(element){
    width = element.width();
    string = element.text().split(' ');
    element.text('');
    reversed = string.reverse();
    var height = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<reversed.length;i++){
        reversed[i] += ' ';
        element.text(element.text()+reversed[i]);
        if (height != element.height()){
            reversed.splice(i,0,"<br/>");
            i++;
        }
        height = element.height();
        console.log(element.height());
    }
    element.html(reversed.reverse().join(''));
}
```

Comment: How are you testing for line breaks?

Comment: Basically what this function does, is takes the container, removes it's contents, places them in one at a time, starting with the last one. It checks to see if the height of the container changes after each insert, wherever the height changes there needs to be a line break. So it remembers where the line breaks need to go, and places them accordingly in the non-reversed text.

Answer (score 1):

Their is a plugin in jquery called [bacon](http://baconforme.com/)

With this you can wrap text according to your needs in any shape you want, I know you have to do a stuff over it but I think it may help you .

```
$(".baconMe").bacon({
    'type' : 'bezier',
    'c1' : { x : 10,        y : 0  },
    'c2' : { x : -115,      y : 170 },
    'c3' : { x : 35,        y : 340 },
    'c4' : { x : 15,        y : 480 },
    'align'  : 'right'
}
```

Comment: Firstly, i dont see how this could possibly work for what i am looking for. I want the text to wrap from bottom to top, leaving the top line to be the shortest, not to a shape (I can not do a special case, because this text could be anything). Secondly, I ended up figuring out a way to write a correct answer, and I posted it below. Thirdly, I tried applying a straight line with a negative slope, it made my text invisible, I tried trouble shooting, but did not know how it was trying to work at all (and the documentation is sub-par), so i gave up, and wrote my own.