# Wrap text from bottom to top

Tags: css, text

Anybody know how I could wrap the text in reverse order, from bottom to top?
I attached an example image.

[[image]][https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVsIG.jpg]

Instead of breaking the line after it is full and having an incomplete line at the end, I need to brake somehow from bottom to top, so bottom lines are full and top line is incomplete.

Comment: Pretty ambiguous question, but I'm going to go with: `float:right`

Comment: You need `writing-mode:bt-lr;` which is not supported by the most common browsers by now. http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-writing-modes-20121115/ and: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/writing-mode

Comment: this is arabic or chinese text flow, not what I need here.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question over here which might be helpful...
 http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15833/text-wrapping-fill-last-line-first

Comment: You could trick the text into breaking into a new line by adding a transparent `<div>` at the upper right of *This is what I..* forcing it to break to a new line. Won't be very clean though.

Comment: @AdiCumpanasu I think the point is, it doesn't have to be Arabic or Chinese, just use the rule for English text.

Comment: Does it need to be responsive? Like, adjust to the browser width or adding text dynamically?

Comment: Adi, I posted a working demo below, does that answer your question?

Comment: why would you want it in the first place? maybe your problem could be solved in a different way?

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommend using exotic CSS attributes which aren't even in Chrome & Firefox yet. The best cross-browser solution is to handle this in Javascript when the document loads. Here's a sketch of how to do that:

```
$(function() {
    $(".title").each(function(i,title) {
        var width = 0;
        var originalHeight = $(title).height();
        var spacer = $('<div style="float:right;height:1px;"/>').prependTo(title);
        while (originalHeight == $(title).height()) {
            spacer.width( ++width );
        }
        spacer.width( --width );
    });
});
```

Working JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/hfuu3m49/1/

Comment: this code is amazing. so explained: you are adding an invisible div/spacer before the text(height:1px; float:right). So the text will float to its left and its bottom. Now the only thing left to do is to calculate the spacer's width to break the first line in such a way that the last is full. You are doing it by increasing the spacer's with until the parent div containing the text will not increase in height due to the text being split to one more line.

Comment: Thanks Adi. Feel free to mark as correct answer if you're happy.

Comment: @AdiCumpanasu You should accept this answer. It's amazingly clean and generic.

Answer (score 2):

6 years later, but fret not! I have found a pure CSS solution!

Turns out you can achieve this result with flexbox, but it's not obvious or very straight forward. This is what I started out with:

[image: A CSS card with text wrongly aligned]

I want the header to be "bottom-heavy", the same effect as you describe in the question.

I began by splitting up my string by whitespace and giving them each a <span> parent. By using flex-wrap: wrap-reverse, and align-content: flex-start. You will achieve this:

[image: The same image as before, but the last word has now been overflowed upwards, making it read the wrong way!]

Oh no! Now the order is messed up! Here comes the trick. By reversing both the order in which you add spans to the HTML and the direction order of flex with 'flex-direction: row-reverse', you actually achieve the "pyramid-shaped"  upwards overflow effect you desire.

[image: The text is now in the proper order, with most of it being at the bottom, creating the desired effect.]

Here is my (simplified) code, using react and react-bootstrap:

```
        <Row className='d-flex flex-wrap-reverse flex-row-reverse align-content-start'>
          {props.deck.name
            .split(' ')
            .reverse()
            .map(word => (
              <span className='mr-1'>{word}</span>
            ))}
        </Row>
```

Comment: The order of the text in the markup is now reversed, so anyone using a screen reader will hear "English Words Everyday" instead of "Everyday English Words". Other technology, like search engines' crawler bots, will also see the text in the wrong order.

Comment: Valid critisim!

Answer (score 1):

There is no general css solution for it. You must have to utilize help of any language.
This is one of the solution using PHP:

```
<?php
$str= "This is what I want to achieve with your help";
$str = strrev($str);
$exp = str_split($str,18);
$str = implode(">rb<", $exp);
echo strrev($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that is depending on the text, then you can try something like a word replacer. For example

```
var words = "This is what I want to achieve";
var newWords.replace("what", "what <br />"); // note the line break
document.write(newWords);
```

Here is a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Ume85/

Otherwise, I don't think you can break a line depending on number of characters in a line.

Comment: this is a manual approach, or if you could automate it with javascript, in a large page with a lots of titles needed like this.... it would take too long and it would be visible only after document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap and Nowrap will be rendered by the client-browser, so you can not force the browser to wrap from bottom to top. but you can do that with javascript or asp.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a formal solution for this problem. But see if this helps.

The HTML CODE

```html
<div id="mydiv">
I can imagine the logic behind the code having to detect what is the last line, detect the div size, and the font size... then measure how many characters it can fit and finally go to the above line and insert the break where necessary. Some font families might make this harder, but trial and error should solve the issue once the basic code is set..
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#mydiv
{
    width:1000px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:justify;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Here setting the div width around 50 times that of the font-size will give you the precise result. Other width values or font values might slightly disorient the last line, giving some blank space after the last character.(Could not solve that part, yet).

JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //GET the total height of the element
        var height = $('#mydiv').outerHeight();

        //Get the height of each line, which is set in CSS
        var lineheight = $('#mydiv').css('line-height');

        //Divide The total height by line height to get the no of lines.
        var globalHeight = parseInt(height)/parseInt(lineheight);
        var myContent = $('#mydiv').html();
        var quotient = 0;

        //As long as no of lines does not increase, keep looping.
        while(quotient<=globalHeight)
        {
            //Add tiny single blank space to the div's beginning
            $('#mydiv').html('&#8239;'+myContent);

            //Get the new height of line and height of div and get the new no of lines and loop again.
            height = $('#mydiv').outerHeight();
            lineheight = $('#mydiv').css('line-height');
            quotient = parseInt(height)/parseInt(lineheight);
            myContent = $('#mydiv').html();
        }
        //get the final div content after exiting the loop.
        var myString = $('#mydiv').html();

        //This is to remove the extra space, which will put the last chars to a new line.
        var newString = myString.substr(1); 
        $('#mydiv').html(newString);
    });
```

Comment: It appears as though you're trying to use Stack Snippets, but not quite getting how it works. Right now you have three separate snippets, so running, say, the second snippet shows no result, since there is no HTML for the CSS to apply to. Consider [trying it out at the sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here).

Comment: Actually, my intention was not to put a Snippet there. I just wanted my code to be highlighted as a code(Using simple code option now). But yes, you are right when you said that i did not quite get how it works. Thank you for the Sandbox link. Am always eager to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know where you want your breaks to take place just use simple HTML breaks to break your content and have it display the way you want.

```
<p>This is what<br/>
want to acheive with your help</p>
```

If you set the breaks manually (and you know where you want them to break) then create them yourself.

You could also try setting separate css width adjustments based on the dimensions of the screen you are seeing the breaking you are not liking and set an @media reference to make the div width smaller to break the text so it doesn't run unevenly across the top of certain size devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on the text `div`.

Comment: Do you have any more explanation to provide?

Answer (score 0):

`flex-wrap` `wrap` `reverse` `display` `direction: rtl;` `map`s to return a `span.style.direction = "ltr"` element `"".split().reverse().map()` Array to subsequently append each to the child `id="root"`, ascending by last then latest.

```js
function App() {
  const result = `This is what I want to achieve with your help.`
    .replaceAll("\n", " ")
    .replaceAll(/[ ]+/g, " ")
    .replaceAll(" ", " ~/")
    .split("~/")
    .reverse()
    .map((x) => {
      const span = document.createElement("span");
      span.style.direction = "ltr";
      span.style.margin = "0px 1px";
      //console.log(span);
      span.innerHTML = x;
      return span;
    })
  //console.log(result);
  return result;
}

App().map(x => document.getElementById("root").appendChild(x));
```

```css
.latest-ascending-from-last-new-word {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="root" class="latest-ascending-from-last-new-word"></div>
```