# Reverse line break?

Tags: css, flexbox

Short & sweet question (which probably has been answered already, but I couldn't find it or figure out what keywords to Google for):
is there a way to achieve this (with CSS? Flexbox?)

If I have this scentence:
**This is a long scentence and it needs to break.**

It now (by default) breaks like this:
**This is a long scentence and it 

needs to break.**

I would like it to break like this:
**This is a long 

scentence and it needs to break.**
So: I would like to have 'the long bit' at the end, not at the beginning.
Is that possible? and if YES: how?

THX!

Comment: `This is a long<br /> scentence and it needs to break.` like that?

Comment: Wrap both “parts” of the text into spans, and make those inline-block? https://jsfiddle.net/jtL2veru/ - change the div width using your browser dev tools, to see how it behaves in different situations.

Comment: In HTML you can use `<wbr>` or `&shy;`  
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

Comment: Thanks all. Thing is: I don't know the scentence beforehand. It can be anything (comes from database). So I can not hardcode linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think want you want to do is possible with vanilla CSS, and it makes sense if you think about it; It won't know where to make that first line break until it knows how many total lines there will be, and it doesn't know how many lines the text will take up until it renders them.

So to my understanding it would need to render the content twice, not just on load but also on resize, which could add to overhead.

A similar question:
[Wrap text from bottom to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423951/wrap-text-from-bottom-to-top)

Comment: hmmm. that sound pretty logical 
But unfortunatly not what I was looking for. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<p> This is a long<br /> sentence and it needs to break. </p>`