# Align multiline text from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

Maybe that's not the best title so here is an example:
A div with fixed width that contains a span with three words.

```
<div id="something" href="#something">
<span>Some mysterious text</span>
</div>
```

Now they appear as:

Some mysterious

text

What I want is:

Some

mysterious text

In other words, I want the text (whatever text, not just in my the three words example) to fill the width starting with the bottom line first and then move upwards. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/sa07qbre/)

Comment: If there are going to be only 3 words there, then use a simple `<br>` after the first word.

Comment: Changing/reducing the width of the div is the most elegant solution.

Comment: @mevius, in my case the width is and should be fixed.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic CSS solution for this. +1 Interesting question though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `br tag`:

```
<span>Some <br />mysterious text</span>
```

Or, you can use width for the span:

```
#something span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sa07qbre/1/)

Comment: Correct, but I want something more generic. I want whatever text I put, to fill the width starting with the bottom line first and then move upwards.

Comment: @ C-link Nepal: Demo doesn't seem to work, try replacing the word mysterious with "abcdefg" for example...

Answer (score 1):

Or use a < br />, like the @C-link Nepal answer, or you change the width of your div.

95px will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding some inline attribute inside your `<span>` and make it `block` will help. Something like this

```
<div id="something" href="#something">
    <span><b>Some</b> mysterious text</span>
</div>
```

**STYLE**

```
span>b{
    font-weight: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sa07qbre/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

"In other words, I want the text to fill the bottom line first"

Crazy idea: If you can determine how many white space characters you can fit into that span before it wraps the text and expand it to a second line, you could write a javascript code to append the text to the end of this set of characters and remove them as you populate the span, then it would fill the area in a bottom-up kind of way.

Found something similar that can help you here:
[jquery/css wrap text bottom up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670890/jquery-css-wrap-text-bottom-up)